# Change a Password is not successfull on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, password

i am trying to set a new password for linux Ubuntu 12.04,but on running command
its giving something like this

```
$passwd
Changing password for ubuntu.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
Bad: new password is too simple
Enter new UNIX password:
```

i really don't understand why this is so....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this we have to edit this file `/etc/pam.d/common-password` & we have to done changes like this password

```
  [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so minlen=1 sha512
```

Answer (score 1):

Password complexity rules are generally enforced by PAM. You have two options:

- Use a "complex" (by PAM's definition) password;
- Change the password simplicity rules as part of `pam_cracklib.so` in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, or equivalent.

See `man 8 pam_cracklib` for information about the available options.

Comment: there is nothing like system-auth in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and there is no man page entry for `pam_cracklib`

Comment: Is root allowed to set the passwords of other users and override the check? Part of me thinks it can, but it's been a while, and none of my systems use pam_cracklib to test.

Answer (score 1):

An installation of Ubuntu requires a minimum password length of 8 characters. (This was changed a few years ago, but I think they kept the installer with a shorter password length to make it easier to setup a user during installation).

With superuser or root privileges, you need to edit a file called `/etc/pam.d/common-password.`

Comment: how should i edited this `/etc/pam.d/common-password` so that it can accept the password which is being acceptable by the same platform like other systems.

Comment: Sorry Ayush Joshi for late reply. Just check out these links, will surely help you out. http://blog.subaquatic.net/archives/setting-up-stronger-password-policy-rules-in-linux/                          http://askubuntu.com/questions/113682/how-to-change-disable-password-complexity-test-when-changing-password

Comment: No problem....actually i also completely forgot about my own question but your suggestion is really helpful & got the solution for this..............                       Thanks Much Adi...